# SSL Client Authentication Failure

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, certificate-authority, client

I have a setup where the client wants to make https call to the server. The client has a certificate installed on the machine The trust chain of the cert:
Root CA
       |----Issuer Certificate
                          |------ Client Certificate

The server listening, on this endpoint, validates the client by building the chain root. ( Note: the server does not have the client certificate installed, it has only the Root Cert in its local mmc or cert store)

The setup used to work, till we have to roll over the cert. We created a new Cert ( we have already tried 3 new certs) with the same attributes as earlier cert, but now the client is not being authenticated by the server.

Strangely, if we install the Issuer (intermediate) cert on the server manually, the authentication goes through.

we cannot figure, what is wrong with the setup or the cert. Any possible help or debugging way ahead will be huge help.

(PS: We use TLS1.0)

Answer (score 1):

> Strangely, if we install the Issuer (intermediate) cert on the server manually, the authentication goes through.

It looks like the client is not sending the necessary intermediate certificate but only the lead certificate or the leaf certificate and some older intermediate certificate.

Comment: It may also be that the client isn't sending any intermediate certs but that the old cert's intermediary is in the server's cert store